# Checking for self-assignment in operator=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was looking at the code examples in the fifth version of C++ Primer. On page 512 they give sample code for `operator=` as follows:

```
HasPtr& HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs)
{
    auto newp = new string(*rhs.ps); // copy the underlying string
    delete ps;                       // free the old memory
    ps = newp;                       // copy data from rhs into this object
    i = rhs.i;
    return *this;                    // return this object
}
```

They argue correctly that if you do things in this order things will work fine even for self assignment. But, I have always seen the recommendation that the check is done explicitly:

```
HasPtr& HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs == this) return *this;  // early exit if self assignment

    auto newp = new string(*rhs.ps); // copy the underlying string
    delete ps;                       // free the old memory
    ps = newp;                       // copy data from rhs into this object
    i = rhs.i;
    return *this;                    // return this object
}
```

This avoids the extra memory allocation/deallocation step.

Can anyone explain why they emphasize writing code that handles self-assignment without just exiting early on self assignment?

Comment: I think they just forget

Comment: If you have code that's doing so many self assignments that you benefit from adding a check for it, you need to rethink your design. Required reading: [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: in the example you provided self assignment will happen, there's no check against this

Comment: @Praetorian are you doing so many dereferences on null pointers that this is the reason why you always want to assure that pointer is valid?

Comment: @Praetorian: Does that mean that my code should never check for edge cases because a well designed program simply wouldn't allow them?

Comment: @EdS. Not always, but in general, yes. I'd argue that you need to worry about minutiae like self-assignment and such when you're writing a low-level resource owning RAII wrapper. Otherwise, pointers, like the one the OP has shown, should be wrapped in a smart pointer anyway.

Comment: @EdS.: No, simply that a well designed program handles edge cases as a matter of course.

Comment: @piotruś I tend to avoid null pointer checks by preferring references over pointers as arguments whenever I can. Also, that's not an apples to apples comparison - lots of self assignments is most likely a sign of something amiss, whereas if you have a pointer argument you're telling the caller passing `nullptr` is valid (documentation stating otherwise notwithstanding).

Comment: @Praetorian what about void pleaseDontPassNullPtrToMe( void* p); can we check for a nullptr in it? do we do it because there was so many call to it with nullptr?

Comment: @Praetorian: Sure, I agree with that, but when I'm designing a type I will definitely check for edge cases and enforce invariants.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I think you misunderstood me.  Of course a well designed program handles edge cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have always seen the recommendation that the check is done explicitly

You've been looking in the wrong places, see e.g. *C++ Coding Standards* by Sutter & Alexandrescu.

Self-assignment is exceedingly rare in most programs, so an explicit check adds a small cost to every self-assignment even though the check is almost always false.  If you write your assignment operator to be correct even in the case of self-assignment then you do not get the cost of the check in the vast majority of cases, and if self-assignment happens it still works.

Sutter & Alexandrescu shows an assignment operator written in terms of a `swap` member:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
{
  Foo(other).swap(*this);
  return *this;
}
```

This is safe against self-assignment, exception-safe, and re-uses the copy constructor so you don't have to implement the assignment explicitly.

Comment: Nice example. I "learned" C++ over 20 years ago - but my original textbook doesn't even mention self assignment for `operator=` in the main text. With broader adoption of C++11 I'm trying to clean up the corners of my knowledge, and I like this example more than some of the others I've seen which don't pass Foo by reference.

Comment: @NathanS Please note that this definition, as well as the even simpler [copy-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), may miss two opportunities for optimization, e.g. for a `vector`: (1) if its capacity is larger than the new object, we don't need to reallocate; (2) an element assignment may be more efficient than destruction+construction. Unlike self-assignment, these cases are not at all rare.

Answer (score 2):

What is important is that the code works correctly under self-assignment (or self-copy), including exception safety. Given this, the question whether the implementation includes an explicit self-test is then mainly a matter of performance. But whether one or the other option is better, depends on use. E.g. if self-operations happen very infrequently or never, tests themselves make code slower.

So using self-tests without actual performance measurements may be an instance of premature optimization. I have seen the opposite recommendation, e.g. in Stroustrup's book, that one avoids self-tests unless measurements show that they make sense.

Comment: Actually, in the 3rd edition of The C++ Programming Language he recommends doing the check in the main text, and then suggests how to optimize around it in the appendix. But, I didn't read the appendix last time I went through the book.

Comment: Well, just checked the index now---it's on p. 382 and p. 508 of the fourth edition, discussing the design of a `vector` and a `Matrix`, respectively. In both cases, he argues that self-assignment is so rare that "the efficiency gained from the test (in the rare case) is more than offset by its cost (in the common case)". He usually repeats that "..as ever, discussions about efficiency are meaningless without measurements".

Comment: I guess I need to get the latest version. :)

Answer (score 0):

If we discard the assumption that the author of the book just wanted to stretch the brain of the reader we may assume that the assignment operator written the way the author suggested may be used to trim down the internal dynamic buffers (or do some other useful things). For example, with `std::vector` you need to do `vector(me).swap(me);` to trim the memory, whereas with fancy assignment operator you can just say `me=me;`.

Comment: Just because an assignment operator safely handle self-assignment does not mean you should rely on side effects of implementation details as a feature

Comment: "*with `std::vector` you need to do `vector(me).swap(me);` to trim the memory*" - that was addressed in C++11 with the introduction of the [`vector::shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) method.